# Add Time which is in text format

Tags: excel

I am running a report that gives me an extract of system data in text format.

Couple of columns list the elasped time in text format. 
E.g. 3H:22M:13S.  And  8H:00M:00S

Can I run a excel formula or macro to find the difference between the two times?

Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the times are in A1 and B1, with the later of the two in B1:

=MMULT(0+SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:B1,"H",""),"M",""),"S",""),{-1;1})

Format cell as [h]:mm:ss

Regards

Comment: Obviously I'd need a bit more information than "it doesn't work"! What were the strings in A1 and B1 on which you tested the formula? What result did the formula give?

Comment: Thanks XOR LX. It was an issue with Excel file. It works for all values where cell2>cell1.  However it doesnot work for cell1>cell2. Assume: Cell A1=1H:24M:01S B1= 0H:15M:00S   C1 (should be)= 1:09:01. But instead it shows "##########...".

Comment: Of course - that was the caveat I stated in my first post. Try this version and let me know: =MMULT(0+SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:B1,"H",""),"M",""),"S",""),{-1;1}*-1^(A1>B1))

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am still getting an error. Can I upload the file or email to you so that you could check the error? Error is about the format*incorrect #VALUE

Comment: Sure. If you have a suitable siteshare I'd be happy to take a look.